# How to plan fixtures for a soccer league?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I want to generate fixtures for a league tournament. This is all I have so far:

```
WEEK 1

team0 vs team1
team2 vs team3
team4 vs team5
team6 vs team7
team8 vs team9

WEEK 2

team2 vs team0
    
WEEK 3

team0 vs team3
    
WEEK 4

team4 vs team0
    
WEEK 5

team0 vs team5
    
WEEK 6

team6 vs team0
    
WEEK 7

team0 vs team7
    
WEEK 8

team8 vs team0
    
WEEK 9

team0 vs team9
```

as you may see I have only team0 fixtures for all 9 weeks. How can I generate the remaining fixtures from there? I have found some generators online but these only can generate the fixtures randomly and I need them to part from this specific order.

Thank you.

Comment: generate them randomly then rearrange the weeks so that team 0 plays team k in week k.

Comment: that wont work because you will have duplicates or missing fixtures. I need a more systematic way to do it so there is no mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem of edge-colouring a complete graph $K_{n}$ with $n-1$ (or $n$) colours.

It has an elegant solution:

[image]

> Soifer (2008) provides the following geometric construction of a coloring in this case: place $n$ points at the vertices and center of a regular $(n − 1)$-sided polygon. For each color class, include one edge from the center to one of the polygon vertices, and all of the perpendicular edges connecting pairs of polygon vertices.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring),

After you did the colouring, let pairs connected with red colour play in week 1, pairs with blue colour in week 2 and so on.

Comment: Looks interesting but I have 10 teams and the polygon has only 8 vertices. Should I add 2 more vertices? Where?

Comment: Yes, the picture is given for 8 teams.

Answer (score 0):

I started with a random arrangement I found online. Then, I rearranged the labels of the teams to make sure the week 1 matchups were what you wanted. Then, I also had to rearrange the labeling of the weeks after the first week to have team 0 play team k in week k.

Week opponents
1  0  1
1  2  3
1  4  5
1  6  7
1  8  9
2  0  2
2  4  1
2  6  3
2  8  5
2  9  7
3  0  3
3  1  5
3  2  7
3  4  9
3  6  8
4  0  4
4  6  2
4  8  1
4  9  3
4  7  5
5  0  5
5  3  7
5  1  9
5  2  8
5  4  6
6  0  6
6  8  4
6  9  2
6  7  1
6  5  3
7  0  7
7  5  9
7  3  8
7  1  6
7  2  4
8  0  8
8  9  6
8  7  4
8  5  2
8  3  1
9  0  9
9  7  8
9  5  6
9  3  4
9  1  2

Comment: Well, thank you for doing all the hard work but I guess there must be an easiest way to do it other than manually, right?